# How to differentiate tags in single Div when parsing HTML via simple_html_dom in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using simple_html_dom in PHP to parse a live HTML page. But I got stock in the following situation. I have a div selector that has a nested span.

```
<div class="name1">Text1, has comma
<span class="name2">, Text2</span>
</div>
```

When I use the following code:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=name1]') as $Results)
$text= $Results->xmltext;
```

Then I get a string of:

```
"Text1, has comma, Text2"
```

because both "Text1, has comma" and "text2" are part of div that has 'class=name1'.

What I need is to have separate texts of "Text1, has comma" and "Text2". I am able to extract "text2" using nested match out of it, but I cannot extract "text1" only.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php

Comment: thanks, but I think my contents must b XML nt HTML, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$text1 = "Text1, has comma, Text2"` and `$text2 = ", Text2"` you could use `substr_replace()`:

```
$text1 = substr_replace($text1, '', -(strlen($text2)));
```

Comment: true, but is there alternative? Like "foreach($html->find('div[class=name1]!span') as $Results)"

Comment: I'm sure there are several alternate ways! `$Results->first_child()`, `SimpleXMLElement`, a recursive loop looking at all `$Results->children()`, etc. As far as using a magic selector that conditionally returns 1 or 2 string results in a single call call to `->find()`, good luck with that.